# Drivers for PCI-GPIB IEEE 488.2 PCI card?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

If anyone has drivers for PCI-GPIB IEEE 488.2 (National Instruments Manufacturer) card can you share it please. I am trying to install the drivers for this card (1998).

[image: Picture of the card]

The card is old since I would not like to go for newer drivers from the official National instruments site since I have a 16 bit program that needs to access the card. Also the driver CD that came with card is now molded which is not useful anymore.

[image: What I get in device manager]

I have also tried to install drivers with snappy driver tool manager it did not work.

Driver needs to be installed in Windows XP SP3 operating system which isn't being supported by the site anymore.

https://www.ni.com/en-us/support/documentation/compatibility/06/ni-488-2-operating-systems-support.html

Answer (score 2):

According to the
[NI-488.2 Operating Systems Support](https://www.ni.com/fr-fr/support/documentation/compatibility/06/ni-488-2-operating-systems-support.html),
the latest NI-488.2 version that works for XP is version 2.4.
(For comparison, today's latest version is 20.0.)

Unfortunately, we are informed in the article
[How to Download NI-488.2 Drivers Prior to 17.6](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z0000019QOfSAM)
that:

> National Instruments has removed NI-488.2 17.0 and earlier from the
> [NI-488.2 Download Page](http://www.ni.com/en-us/support/downloads/drivers/download.ni-488-2.html). If you require an earlier version of the NI-488.2 driver, please reach out to [NI Support](http://www.ni.com/contact-us/) to request for the specific driver version.

Nevertheless, Google has found some download sites for version 2.4
(unverified by myself):

- [488.2 GPIB DRIVERS For Vista 32bit/ XP 32bit/ 2K/ Me/ NT/ Windows 98/ DOS](https://www.icselect.com/gpib_install%204882.html)
- [NI-488.2 (Win32) Version 2.4 for Windows 2000/XP](https://labview360.com/download/show.asp?id=1)

If none of these versions works for you, you will need to contact
NI Support for the driver.

Answer (score 0):

Please find under this link the list of links to download NI 488.2 GPIB Drivers.
https://www.eevblog.com/forum/testgear/ni-gpib-vintage-driver-for-windows98se/msg4130899/#msg4130899

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1152742)